# How to check if user is actively editing a cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a very simple script that is triggered every 15 minutes to re-alphabetize a sheet based on that day's date. It works perfectly, except for one issue. The sheet is used by about 8-10 users at any given time. If a user is actively typing in a cell when the function is triggered and the sheet is resorted, then when they finish typing the cell they have edited the wrong cell. For example, if they start editing cell D24, and then after it is resorted that row becomes D28, then when they hit enter they will overwrite the new D24.

Is there any way I could incorporate something in the code to check if there are any cells that are actively being edited (greyed out because someone is inside it)? Or some other solution that would solve this issue?

```
function Alphabetize() {

var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
var now = new Date();
  var name = Utilities.formatDate(now,"EST","MM-dd")
  var day = now.getDay()

  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(name)
  var col = sheet.getLastColumn()
  var row = sheet.getLastRow()

  var range = sheet.getRange(3, 1, row, col)

 range.sort({column: 1, ascending: true})


}
```

Comment: Throw a modal dialog in their face, when the function runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since modals don't work in this situation (time based triggers and other users) I figured out a slightly clunky work around. I added a row at the top of the sheet in the frozen section that is bright yellow and says "Press Enter. Sheet about to re-sort." multiple times so it's visible across the entire sheet. I then hid that row and inserted this code right before it sorts:

```
sheet.showRows(2)
Utilities.sleep(10000)
```

So it shows that row, waits for 10 seconds, sorts and then hides the row again with `sheet.hideRows(2)`. Elegant, it is not. But it works on the time trigger and every user sees it. If there's a more elegant solution, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way I could incorporate something in the code to check if there are any cells that are actively being edited (greyed out because someone is inside it)?

I think that this could be possible by using a web browser extension that reads the spreadsheet DOM but it will not very dependable as the web page source of many Google apps are generate automatically and anything could change without previous notice.

By one hand, the status identified by the web browser extension should be saved on a document / script store by using the Properties Service or the Cache Service so the time-driven trigger could read the status and by the other, the time-driven trigger save a flag to warn the user using the same services so the web browser could read them.

NOTE: In order to make this work, the web browser should call functions from the same project of the functions ran by the time-driver trigger.

By using Google Apps Script you could use spreadsheet.toast(...) to show a modeles and non so intrusive warning, then use a modal dialog to interrupt the user.

Comment: That doesn't work for two reasons. This uses a time based trigger, so the modal dialog or toast won't run since it's being triggered behind the scenes. It would work if it's ran manually, but not with a time trigger. Second, I really need it to notify other users who are using the sheet and when it's ran manually it only is thrown for the user who runs it. The other users see nothing. They would have to run it themselves, which defeats the point.

Comment: I added a bit more details: use the properties / cache services.

Comment: By the way, the question asks for "any way" not for a pretty one ;)